# rails 4.1.6 scope: in model not responding properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi i am in a bit of a bind here because i am trying to use scope and cant seem to make it work.

I am now using it in my model section like so.

```
has_many :friends, through: :user_friendships,
                    scope -> {where(user_friendships: { state: 'accepted' })}
```

also before i was using it like so from the turorials and i found out it was depricated and had to re adjust the code that i used above but the problem is that it also encountered an error

```
has_many :friends, through: :user_friendships,
                conditions: { user_friendships: { state: 'accepted' }}
```

this was the error that i encountered while using the first line of code and the second line of code in the terminal

```
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:71:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :scope. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table (ArgumentError)
```

if anybody can help me with this problem it would really be great and appreciated! also i am a bit of a noob in rails so i might not understand properly the syntax that you might put in the answer so can you pls. make it noob friendly and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the word `scope` in there. The lambda should just be given as the second argument to `has_many`:

```
has_many :friends, ->{ where(user_friendships: { state: 'accepted' }) },
                   through: :user_friendships
```

You can see more examples in the [Active Record Assocations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many).

**Edit:** Here's the method signature from the [docs for `has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> `has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)`

In your code:

1. `:friends` is the `name` argument
2. `->{ where(...) }` is the `scope` argument
3. `{ through: :user_friendships }` is the `options` argument (but Ruby lets us omit the `{}` for a Hash when it's the last argument).

Comment: hi thanks for the fix it is now working properly now trying to do this   conditions: { state: 'pending' }   and tried like your answer like this :    has_many :pending_user_friendships,class_name: 'UserFriendship',          foreign_key: :user_id,          ->{ where(user_id: { state: 'pending'})}     apparently it doesnt work as i expected it too

Comment: Like I said, the lambda (the `->{ ... }` bit) needs to be the second argument, i.e. after `:pending_user_friendships` and before `class_name: ...`.